# What is the best way to add and keep track of an indefinite amount of objects?

Tags: objective-c, nsarray

I have a button that, when tapped, adds a label inside a view. Anytime it is tapped after that, it adds another label that starts where the last one ended.

I tried this

```
if (self.currentLabel == nil)  
     startingPoint = 0;
else
    startingPoint = currentLabel.frame.size.width + 5;

// Most recently created label becomes currentLabel
self.currentLabel = [[FormulaLabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(startingPoint, 10, 100, 50)];
```

To keep track of all the labels, I tried adding them to an array

```
 [arrayOfObjects addObject:self.currentLabel]
```

but I noticed that the array count wasn't changing.

Why doesn't the above code work, and is there a better way to keep track of an indefinite amount of labels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[NSArrays](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSArray) are immutable. You need to use an [NSMutableArray](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

If you are already using a NSMutableArray, are you getting any warnings?

As an additional note, "arrayOfObjects" is a poor name.  Something like "labels," "usedLabels" or "labelHistory" would be far more descriptive.

Comment: The problem was that I never allocated the array. Is the code in general poor design though?

Comment: You should update your question if you have solved your issue.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using an array to keep track of objects, and other than the naming, nothing wrong with the small snippet you posted.  You might to get in the habit of writing if (nil == self.currentLabel) though - that way the compiler will throw an error if you accidentally type = instead of ==.